# inApp purchasing for iphone before app has been submitted

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add in-app purchasing to my iphone app, but it is a brand new app, and not in the app store. I would like to add buttons so when the user clicks on them, they are directed to the app store to purchase that feature. How is this accomplished without app having a link on the app store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app purchasing does not work through the App Store, but rather through your own UI. You can find the docs below on how to build your own "Store Front".

[Full docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

["Store Front"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH101-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

In App Purchases themselves are not on the App Store. They are in your app but *locked*. So in the end you don't need any link to the store.